# Auto-filling React input with data and being able to edit onChange

Tags: reactjs, input, state

I have a view with multiple forms, each containing checkboxes and a comments box. These start off completely empty and are sent up one by one (you can't access one without closing another). Once you've posted one form, the next time you access this page it auto-fills these fields with the relevant values.

I have this working to the point where I can start the process from the first form and complete it. All good. When I come back to this page, the data auto-fills the forms as expected and I'm able to edit the checkboxes which builds an object based on a structure provided to me in the options state. The problem arises from the comments input field. I'm having trouble being able to edit the pre-filled data and determining whether or not there is data present in the field and acting accordingly. At the moment, it seems to edit one letter and then lose focus.

As you can see from the `onChange` in the `componentRendererHandler` I send up an object structure to build from.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Validator from 'validatorjs';

import FormScene from 'ms/scenes/FormScene';
import Base from 'ms/scenes/Base';
import CheckBox from 'ms/components/Form/CheckBox';
import FieldLabel from 'ms/components/Form/FieldLabel';
import FormInput from 'ms/components/Form/FormInput';
import Notification from 'ms/components/Notification';

import distinctRule from 'ms/utility/customValidatorRules';
import { post, get } from 'ms/services/api';

import styles from './styles.scss';
const Questionnaire = props => {
    const [usersCurrentSelection, setUsersCurrentSelection] = useState(null);
    const [endPoint, setEndPoint] = useState(null);
    const [options, setOptions] = useState(null);
    const [rules, setRules] = useState(null);
    const [id, setId] = useState(null)
    const [closeNotification, setCloseNotification] = useState(1);
    const [loader, setLoader] = useState(1);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState(0);
    const [structure, setStructure] = useState(null);
    const [comments, setComments] = useState(null);
    const [validationErrors, setValidationErrors] = useState(null);
    const [submittedSection, setSubmittedSection] = useState(0);
    const [currentComment, setCurrentComment] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoader(1);
        if (props.state.rules !== null && props.state.rules !== undefined) {
            setOptions(props.state.rules.rules.site_measure);
            setTimeout(() => {
                setLoader(0);
            }, 1000)
        }
        if (props.state.id.id !== null && props.state.id.id !== undefined) {
            setId(props.state.id.id);
            get(`api/deal/${props.state.id.id}`)
            .then(res => {
                setUsersCurrentSelection(res.data.site_measure.questionnaire);
                setStructure(res.data.site_measure.questionnaire);
                setCurrentComment(res.data.site_measure.questionnaire.data);
                setLoader(0);
            });
        }
        if (options) {
            setEndPoint(options.questionnaire.endpoint);
        }
    }, [props.state, options])

    const closeNotificationHandler = () => {
        setCloseNotification(0);
    }

    const onChange = (e, item, rules) => {
        const currentRules = rules;
        let itemValue = item;
        let section = Object.entries(item)[0][0];
        let currentSelection = usersCurrentSelection;

        setRules(currentRules);

        if (usersCurrentSelection === null || usersCurrentSelection === undefined) {
            if (!itemValue[section].selection.includes(e.target.value)) {
                itemValue[section].selection.push(e.target.value);
                setStructure({[section]: itemValue[section]});
            } else {
                const index = itemValue[section].selection.indexOf(e.target.value);
                if (index > -1) {
                    itemValue[section].selection.splice(index, 1);
                    setStructure({[section]: itemValue[section]});
                }
            }
        } else if (currentSelection.data[section] !== undefined) {
            if (currentSelection.data[section].selection.includes(e.target.value)) {
                console.log('already has this')
                const index = currentSelection.data[section].selection.indexOf(e.target.value);
                if (index > -1) {
                    currentSelection.data[section].selection.splice(index, 1);
                    setStructure({[section]: currentSelection.data[section]});
                }
            } else {
                console.log('doesn\'t has this')
                if (!currentSelection.data[section].selection.includes(e.target.value)) {
                    currentSelection.data[section].selection.push(e.target.value);
                    setStructure({[section]: currentSelection.data[section]});
                }
            }
        }

        if (currentSelection.data[section] === undefined || currentSelection.data[section] === null) {
            console.log('here')
            if (!itemValue[section].selection.includes(e.target.value)) {
                itemValue[section].selection.push(e.target.value);
                setStructure({[section]: itemValue[section]});
            } else {
                const index = itemValue[section].selection.indexOf(e.target.value);
                if (index > -1) {
                    itemValue[section].selection.splice(index, 1);
                    setStructure({[section]: itemValue[section]});
                }
            }
        }
    }

    const onCommentsChange = (e, commentsStructure, item) => {
        let currentSelection = usersCurrentSelection;
        let currentStructure = structure;
        let section = Object.entries(item)[0][0];

        if (currentSelection.data !== undefined && currentSelection.data[section]) {
            currentSelection.data[section].comments = e.target.value;
            setStructure({[section]: currentSelection.data[section]})
            console.log({[section]: currentSelection.data[section]});
        } else {
            console.log(item);
            console.log(item[section].comments = e.target.value);
        }

        console.log(currentStructure);
    }

    const isArrayUnique = (arr) => {
        return new Set(arr).size !== arr.length ? false : true
    }

    const isCommentPresent = (length, value) => {
        if (length > 1 && (value === null || value === "" || value === '-')) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    const submit = (e, structureFromSubmit, submittedSection) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let currentStructure = structure;
        let section = Object.entries(currentStructure)[0][0];
        let userId = endPoint;
        let endPointWithId = userId.replace('[ID]', id);

        console.log(currentStructure)

        setSubmittedSection(currentStructure);

        if (structure === null) {
            console.log('structure is null');
            setStructure({...structureFromSubmit});
        } else {
            if (!structure[section].comments && structure[section].selection.length > 1) {
                console.log('structure is not null');
                let commentVal = '-';
                currentStructure[section].comments = commentVal;
                setStructure({...currentStructure});
            }
        }

        Validator.register(
            'required_if_array_count_greater_than',
            () => isCommentPresent(structure[section].selection.length, structure[section].comments),
            'More than one option selected without :attribute',
        );

        Validator.register(
            'distinct',
            () => isArrayUnique(structure[section].selection),
            'Duplicate values :attribute',
        );

        let validation = new Validator(structure, rules);
        const validationRes = validation.passes();

        if (validationRes === true) {
            let nextSection = submittedSection + 1;
            setCloseNotification(0);
            setError(0);
            post(endPointWithId, {}, structure)
                .then(res => {
                    setMessage(res.message);
                    setSubmittedSection(nextSection);
                    console.log(res.message);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    setMessage(err.message)
                })
        } else {
            const errorMessage = validation.errors.errors;
            const getFirstError = errorMessage[Object.keys(errorMessage)[0]];
            setError(1);
            setMessage(getFirstError[0]);
            setValidationErrors(errorMessage);
        }
    }

    const componentRenderHandler = (type, options, name, value, structure, rules) => {
        switch (type) {
            case 'checkbox':
                return (
                    <Fragment>
                        <h3 className={styles.subtitle}>{value}</h3>
                        {options.map(option => (
                            <Fragment>
                                <CheckBox
                                    key={option.name}
                                    level={option.order}
                                    id={option.name}
                                    name={name}
                                    label={option.value}
                                    val={option.name}
                                    onChange={e => onChange(e, structure, rules)}
                                    err={error === 1
                                        && validationErrors !== null
                                        && name in validationErrors ? 1
                                        : 0}
                                    preSelected={
                                            usersCurrentSelection !== null
                                            && usersCurrentSelection !== undefined
                                            && usersCurrentSelection.data[Object.entries(structure)[0][0]] !== undefined
                                            ? usersCurrentSelection.data[Object.entries(structure)[0][0]].selection.includes(option.name)
                                            : null}
                                />
                        </Fragment>
                        ))}
                    </Fragment>
                )
            case 'text':
                return (
                    <Fragment>
                        <FieldLabel
                            htmlFor={name}
                            label={value}
                        />
                        <FormInput
                            key={value}
                            type={type}
                            name={name}
                            onChange={e =>
                                onCommentsChange(
                                    e,
                                    usersCurrentSelection !== null ? usersCurrentSelection.data[Object.entries(structure)[0][0]] : null,
                                    structure
                                    )}
                            defaultValue={usersCurrentSelection !== null
                                && usersCurrentSelection !== undefined
                                && usersCurrentSelection.data[Object.entries(structure)[0][0]] !== undefined
                                && (usersCurrentSelection.data[Object.entries(structure)[0][0]].comments !== ""
                                || usersCurrentSelection.data[Object.entries(structure)[0][0]].comments !== null)
                                ? usersCurrentSelection.data[Object.entries(structure)[0][0]].comments
                                : null}
                            err={error === 1
                                && validationErrors !== null
                                && name in validationErrors
                                ? 1
                                : 0}
                        />
                    </Fragment>
                )
        }
    }

    console.log(structure)

    return (
        <Base>
            {options !== null && options !== undefined ?
                <h2
                    className={styles.title}
                >
                    {options.questionnaire.title}
                </h2>
            : null}
            {closeNotification === 0 ?
                <Notification
                    message={message}
                    notificationStatus={error === 0 ? 1 : 2}
                    closeNotification={closeNotificationHandler}
                />
                : null}
            {loader === 1 ? <p>Loading...</p> :
                options.questionnaire.form.map(item => (
                        <FormScene
                            key={item.name}
                            itemIndex={item.order}
                            currentSection={submittedSection}
                            title={item.value}
                            onSubmit={e => submit(e, item.structure, item.order)}
                        >
                            {item.components.map(component =>
                                componentRenderHandler(
                                    component.type,
                                    component.options !== null ? component.options.map(option => option) : null,
                                    component.name,
                                    component.value,
                                    item.structure,
                                    item.rules,
                                ))}
                        </FormScene>
                ))
            }
        </Base>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        state
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Questionnaire);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow your code easily, that said. I'd hazard a guess that you're setting an absolute value to the field that isn't updatable through the onChange the way you'd expect. This leaves it uneditable as it resets to the original value every time you try to make an change.

Comment: @DavidBarker it's entirely possible. I'm setting the comments key value to `currentSelection.data[section].comments = e.target.value` if it exists and then setting the new structure state. Which it does, but only one letter at a time before it unfocuses, possibly to do with re-rendering?

Comment: @DavidBarker this, for example: https://i.gyazo.com/1b95ff80e7c577eb99aebe8d2f8c000a.mp4 the comments input lose focus on every keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are landing on this issue years later like me, this is what I found that works for me.

Using a state for each field, set the states default value to the data that you want to fill your input field in. This example is only for one title input field:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  // define state and set default value to the value of payload.title
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(payload.title);


  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <input
        type='text'
        value={title} // this is the state value
        onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} // update value on change
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```